# Using IF/AND statements to assign specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

After searching multiple answers, I am not finding the proper statement that I am needing to accomplish a formula calculation.

GOAL: Assign a 0, 1.5, 3 value based on criteria established by inputted value.

If cell c26/c25 is less than 2, then I want to assign 0

If cell c26/c25 is = to 2 but also less than 3, then I want to assign 1.5

If cell c26/c25 is = to or greater than 3, then I want to assign a value of 3

I have tried a number of calculations which include IF/AND statements, but values are not returning properly.

Comment: Start by using a basic `if` statement for the first of your conditions. Then add the second one inside the `false` part of the first one.

Comment: You want one value each for C25 and C26? Typically you'd can use nested IF's for this  eg: `IF(TEST1, RESULT1, IF(TEST2, RESULT2, IF(TEST3, RESULT3, DEFAULT)))`

Comment: This is one options that I have tried using...=IF(C26/C25>=3,3,IF(C26/C25>=2,1.5,0))... However, my number is 40 divided by 10 which would equal 4.  My result is returning 1.50 and not 3;

Comment: I have also tried adding an AND statement, but it returns an error message...   =IF(C26/C25>=3,3,IF(AND(C26/C25>=2,c26/c25<3,1.5,0))

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with two nested ifs:

```
=if(C26/C25>=3;3;if(C26/C25>=2;1,5;0))
```

I think it meets all your conditions.

Comment: I tried copying and pasting the above nested formula.  However, it also returned an error similar to what I have been receiving.  Any ideas as to why this might be occuring?

Comment: Which error do you get? Are there numbers in C25 and C26 cells? Maybe you have 0 in C25? Please elaborate.

Comment: C26=40 and C25=10.  So, it is returning a 4.   So, the cell that is reassigning a value should be coming back with a 3.  However, it is returning a 1.50.    To make that above statement work, I had to change the semi-colon to a comma.  It would not work with semi-colon.

Comment: Depending on your settings you may need to use commas and full-stops: `=IF(C26/C25>=3,3,IF(C26/C25>=2,1.5,0))`

Comment: #tospig... that is the exact formula that I am using.  However, it still returns a 1.5.  Not exactly sure when it should be returning a 3 for this calculation.

Comment: It returns 3 when the calculation is `>=3`. so in your example, `C26=40`, `C25=10`, which is evaluated in this part `=IF(C26/C25>=3,3` of the formula, it returns 3.

Comment: #tospig... Correct c26/c25 would equal 4.  Therefore, based on the calculation, I should be returning a 3.  However, it is returning a 1.50.    Not sure this is an option.  If c26/c2>=3, 3, otherwise if c26/c25 is >=2 but less than 2.99 then 1.5, if c26/c25<2 then 0.   Not sure how to correctly write this or if this is the right way to go about it.  Tried so many things... just not getting it to return the correct number.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting 1.5 as the formula in the answer works. Perhaps try it with just `=if(c26/c25>=3,3,"not three")` and see what it gives you?

Comment: I did two things... first of all in the cell for this calculation I placed just a simple =c26/c25.   That returned 4 as expected.  Then, I used your other simple formula... but that returned "not three"???  Should have returned 3.  Very frustrated at this point.

Comment: That's odd. How is the cell formatted? what does `=TYPE(C26/C25)` give you [(for reference)](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/type.php) - might be worth editing your question to add your attempts and the errors

Comment: The =Type returned a 1.    I am just searching for answers now... the cell for c25 has a formula in it ((C16-c17)*10000)*c24  and c26 also has a formula ((c18-c16)*10000)*c24... that should have nothing to do with it, and they are already filled prior to the cell that I am trying to setup.

Comment: On a hunch and gut feeling...  I cleared all contents and formatting.   I then went into the formula field and made sure that all were numbers.  I then re-applied the formula, and it now seems to be working properly.  I am so sorry for the frustration, but thankful for your help.